# View source in tabs, not in windows, with Internet Explorer 10

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

In Internet Explorer 10, when I try `view-source:http://localhost` it redirects me to the app store in Windows 8.

How can I get it like in Chrome?

Comment: View the web page source?

Answer (score 2):

In Internet Explorer, to see the source code of any page, simply go to that page and press <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up Developer Tools.

Comment: Or `View menu / Source` or `right-click / View source`. None of this however solves the OP's query.